# Replace HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project at the moment, migrating an existing site to a new server and make the site work with a new CMS.

The CMS is hideous, with loads of hardcoded content. It's not possible to edit this content in the CMS.

So I have to replace a lot of HTML with JS.

My plan is to replace the HTML with jQuery's replaceWith method.

Is this a sound a approach? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: fix the cms! I assume you've looked at all the options in regard to fixing the cms. You could introduce a stylesheet that hides the areas you don't want, and then add new cms modules for the stuff you do. Or you could use javascript - that'd be my last option though.

Comment: Sadly fixing the CMS is not an opportunity. Being a Textpattern devotee, working with a poor CMS like this is kind of a drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about taking a dom element, clearing out the current content, then adding new content in, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#myelement').empty();
    $('#myelement').append('new stuff');
});
```

.append() inserts into the dom element, after anything that's already in it.

**Edit:**
Just thought of a better way:

```
$('#myelement').html('new content');
```

That replaces the content of dom element selected by that selector with the new content. Basically, it does the same as my first solution, but in one line of code. Of course, if you need to put in multiple things (like a loop that adds options to dropdown by reading from an array), then you'd do the .append() inside that loop.

And .html() keeps Prescott's optimization urges happy with only one paint ;-)

Comment: Does this allow HTML? Like this:
$('#myelement').empty();
$('#myelement').append('<h1>Something</h1>');

Comment: right. obviously, you'd have to do this in the $(document).ready, so that those dom elements exist for you to change

Comment: Only comment to this is that calling .empty() and then .append(stuff) will cause the page to repaint twice. There is probably a way to do this with one repaint, replaceWith() might do this in one, or might hide the empty() under the covers..I'm not sure

Comment: And yea, you can put whatever you want in the append, including html

Comment: @Prescott where do you get that .empty() will cause the page to repaint? It doesn't mention that on the jquery site. All it does is remove the contents of that element. I'm using it and append to fill dropdowns, and acording to what I see in fiddler, it's not refiring anything else

Comment: @Patches changes to the document DOM cause a browser repaint - if you manipulate DOM elements that aren't connected to the document, then attach them at once, you get a single browser repaint.  I'm sorry premature optimization, you likely don't have to worry about it :)

Comment: @timkl note that .replaceWith() will replace the selected dom element entirely, while empty & append will replace the dom element's content. It's basically pick your poison: go with replaceWith if you want to replace everything, including css classes and js events, and empty & append if you only want to touch content

Comment: @Prescott Ah, got ya. Yea, if you want blow away everything and rebuild the page, that'd make sense... LOL - $(html).replaceWith('...totally new html page code from scratch...'); That'd be hilarious - instant thedailywtf post :-)

Comment: @timkl just thought of a better way using the .html() function. Edited my answer to include that.

Comment: @Patches Thanks a lot for helping me out - I'll go with the .html method :)